# Priority queue lambda comparator and normal comparator

Tags: c++, stl, comparator, priority-queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

auto cmp2(const array<int, 2>& a, const array<int, 2>& b) {
    return a[0]+a[1] > b[0]+b[1];
}

int main() {
    auto cmp = [] (const array<int, 2>& a, const array<int, 2>& b) {
        return a[0]+a[1] > b[0]+b[1];
    };

    priority_queue<array<int, 2>, vector<array<int, 2>>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);

    priority_queue<array<int, 2>, vector<array<int, 2>>, decltype(cmp2)> pq2(cmp2);
}
```

There is a lambda comparator in the main function and another comparator outside. Why only the first priority queue can compile while the second one cannot and gives an error of invalidly declared function type.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmp` is a lambda. It's an object with a `()` operator.

But `cmp2()` is a function.

You can't use a function as a callable type, but you can use a function *pointer* as a callable type, in that case you must use `decltype(&cmp)` to get a function pointer type:

```
    priority_queue<array<int, 2>, vector<array<int, 2>>, decltype(&cmp2)> pq2(&cmp2);
```

Comment: Then why cmp in the main function works, isn't a function also?

Comment: `cmp` is a lambda, it's an instance of a class with a `operator()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should have dug deeper before asking this kind of question.

Comment: Is `decltype` actually needed for either example?

Comment: @sweenish `decltype` is needed to get a type, and `decltype(&cmp2)` is needed because the Compare argument defaults to `std::less<T>`.

Comment: Ah. Forgot that the type of the comparator had be explicitly stated.